# naming dictionaries after list items

Tags: python

I have a list like `list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` and am running a for-loop over the items. each time I do so, I'd like to create a dictionary named after the list element currently being looped over. For example

```
for element in list:
    ('%s' + '_' + 'dict') % element = {}
```

which, of course, doesn't work, giving me the error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's possible to use `eval` or to create new entries in the `globals()` dictionary, it's almost certainly a bad idea. Instead, use your dictionary names as keys into another dictionary explicitly:

```
names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

d = {}
for name in names:
    d[name] = {}
```

You could also use a dict comprehension (or a generator expression in the `dict` constructor, if you're in an earlier version of Python that doesn't allow dict comprehensions):

```
d = {name: {} for name in names}
# d = dict((name, {}) for name in names) # generator expression version for pre-2.7
```

Comment: Modifying the `locals` dict doesn't work. Unless you're at global scope, Python doesn't actually store its local variables there, and modifications won't be seen.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to properly refer to things that would actually work (though they'd still be bad ideas).

Comment: @Blckknght: is there any reason to not use dict comprehension? It seems a lot cleaner than your other example, so just curious if there would ever be a reason to not use a dict comprehension

Comment: @user139014: Probably there isn't if creating an empty dictionary is all you need to do for each name. However, if you're just going to do another loop to add stuff to the inner dictionaries immediately afterward, it might make sense to do it all in one step, rather than two. And while you might be able to build the inner dictionaries with nested dict comprehensions, it will get more complicated. In that situation, an explicit loop, like my first version may be better than trying to wedge it all into a single statement.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with a dict. Like:

```
context = {}
for element in list:
    context['%s_dict' % element] = {}
```

After that, you can use context['foo_dict'] to access the dictionaries you created.